# Removing folders that are empty or contain .gitignore file from text file

Tags: bash

I am looking for a clean solution that will allow me to:

- find folders that are either empty or contain .gitignore files
- output them into a text file
- delete the folders
- recreate them at a later point (without the `gitignore`, just the directory structure)

Right now this is what I have:

1) Find folders that are empty or contain .gitignore files and output them to a file

```
dir = $1
find /c/methuselah/$dir/ -name .gitignore > $dir/gitignoredir.txt
find /c/methuselah/$dir/ -type d -empty > $dir/emptydir.txt
```

Sample file content for `gitignoredir.txt:`
/c/methuselah/project/folder1/subfolder1/.gitignore
/c/methuselah/project/folder1/subfolder2/.gitignore
/c/methuselah/project/folder1/subfolder3/.gitignore

`emptydir.txt` contains nothing because empty files all contain a .gitignore file.

2) Deleting the folders

```
dir = $1
filename=$dir/gitignoredir.txt
filelines='cat $filename'
for line in $filelines
do
  echo 'Removing $line'
  rm -rf $line
done
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as it only deletes the .gitignore file. This means that empty folders remain. I want to delete them as part of the deletion process as well. How would I accomplish this in Bash?

Comment: `.txt` is missed at the end of the line `filename=$dir/gitignoredir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way of performing the 2nd phase (*Deleting the folders*):

```
dir=$1
while read -r fn; do rm -rf "${fn%/*}"; done < "$dir/gitignoredir.txt"
```

Comment: The folders aren't deleted, I just get the prompt `/c/methuselah/xxx/xxx: is a directory`.

Comment: @methuselah, make sure that you have specified flag `-f` along with `-r` flag

Answer (score 1):

If your script is working up until the delete but is only deleting the file, you can use the [`dirname`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) tool to get the path up until the last `/` dropping the trailing filename.

change:

```
rm -rf $line
```

to:

```
rm -rf "$(dirname $line)"
```